# Deleting auto key node from firebase android

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not sure if I'm doing this right but I'm creating a Query to get the auto-generated key that is stored in firebase. I want to delete this key from firebase. I'm wondering if this the right process? Like is it possible to just call `removeValue()` on the query or have to use Datasnapshot? My code is as follows. All it does is gets the auto-generated key and prints it.

`DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
String removeQuery = ref.child("EventData").push().getKey();
 System.out.println(removeQuery); 
Log.d(TAG,"Remove Query was called !!!!!!!!!!!!");`

**Updated1**
[image]

**Updated2**

Is there an easy way to set `removeQuery` to null?

Comment: You are creating the pushId. BTW what value that you want to remove?

Comment: @Ticherhaz I have updated the post. I want to delete the highlighted part.

Comment: You need to have your pushId and then you can delete them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
String removeQuery = ref.child("EventData").push().getKey();
```

---

You are creating a new key and storing it inside a variable. You can do that in the beginning (when storing data to the database), add data to `Intent`:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
String removeQuery = ref.child("EventData").push().getKey();
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", removeQuery);
startActivity(intent);
```

then later in the other activity you can delete like this:

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
String key = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
ref.child("EventData").child(key).removeValue();
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#getIntent() get intent is a method inside an activity class if you are using a fragment then use getactivity.getintent

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the pushID which is `M1VA...`. and then you can delete by like this.
Refer to this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#add_a_completion_callback

```
mDatabase.child("EventData").child("M1VA....").removeValue()
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // Write was successful!
                // ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Write failed
                // ...
            }
        });
```